# c# excel format each row in rtf

Tags: c#, excel, loops

I am working on an application that has to convert all the valuables from each row to an rtf document. The excel file that i am using has more than 10.000 rows but only 5 columns.
so far i can read the file using`Value2.ToString` method.
what i would like to do is get the 5 values from each row, provide them with a header

> firsttext= the text of cel a1
>
> secondtext= the text of cel b1
>
> thirdtext= the text of cel c1
>
> fourthtext= the text of cel d1
>
> fifttext= the text of cel e1

and do the same for cel a2, b2 etc etc.
My code so far is

```
           //Create COM Objects. 
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\aaa.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;  
        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        //iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
        //excel is not zero based!!
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                //new line
                if (j == 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

                //write the value to the console
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t", "\r\n");
      
            }
           
           // Console.ReadLine(); for testing purposes         
        }

        //cleanup

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //  rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
        //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
        //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

        //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

        //close and release
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: My question is, how can i read the values from each row and send it to a textfile with the headers as mentioned above, before the cell values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not really sure what your problem is?

Are you just asking on how to add the headers?

```
//iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
//excel is not zero based!!
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        //new line
        if (j == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

        //write the value to the console
        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
           Console.Write("{0}= ", GetHeaderText(j));
           Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t", "\r\n");
    }
   // Console.ReadLine(); for testing purposes         
}
```

Get the header text via some helper method:

```
private string GetHeaderText(int colId)
{
    switch (colId)
    {
        case 1:
           return "firsttext";
        case 2:
           return "secondtext";
        case 3:
           return "thirdtext";
        case 4:
           return "fourthtext";
        case 5:
           return "fithtext";
        default:
           return "header not defined";
    }
}
```